# Having trouble to get the real part of an array obtained from the fun.eval

Tags: python, arrays, list, complex-numbers

I used the eval function to evaluate a function. the code is written below:

```
import numpy as np
import sympy
from sympy import Symbol, Add
s = sympy.Symbol('s')
x = [ s, s+1, 10*s**2, 5]
a = [1 + 1j, 2 , 3 , 4 , 5]
fun = Add(*x) # Create a function by adding all terms. * is to unpack all the values

def F(fun, v):
    return fun.evalf(subs={s: v}) # Evaluate the function at s=v

f_dis = [F(fun, v) for v in a] 
print (f_dis)
fit3 = np.asanyarray(f_dis)
print ("fit3 =", fit3)
realpart = fit3.real[0]
print ("real =", realpart)
```

the result of `f_dis` is

```
[8.0 + 22.0*I, 50.0000000000000, 102.000000000000, 174.000000000000, 266.000000000000]
```

The point here is that the code shows the `8.0 + 22.0*I` as the real part of the first element, instead of showing `8` only.
What should I do to solve this issue?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`re`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/functions/elementary.html#re) from `Sympy` to get only the real part of the evaluated expression

```
import numpy as np
from sympy import Symbol, Add, re

s = Symbol('s')
x = [ s, s+1, 10*s**2, 5]
a = [1 + 1j, 2 , 3 , 4 , 5]
fun = Add(*x) # Create a function by adding all terms. * is to unpack all the values

def F(fun, v):
    return fun.evalf(subs={s: v}) # Evaluate the function at s=v

f_dis = [re(F(fun, v)) for v in a] # <---- Use re() here
print (f_dis)
# [8.00000000000000, 50.0000000000000, 102.000000000000, 174.000000000000, 266.000000000000]
```